# Convert all Rows to Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

Trying to Convert Rows to Multiple columns in SQL Server as show below:

**Current result:**

```
PortCode    CarCode
------------------------
AAB         A5
ADR         BH
SAN         QQ
```

**Expected result:**

```
PortCode   CarCode   PortCode  CarCode   PortCode   CarCode
-----------------------------------------------------------
AAB        A5        ADR       BH        SAN        QQ
```

Tried with`PIVOT` but didn't helped.

Can anyone please explain me, how to achieve it?

Comment: Show the code you used for the pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then portcode end) as portcode_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then carcode end) as carcode_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then portcode end) as portcode_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then carcode end) as carcode_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then portcode end) as portcode_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then carcode end) as carcode_3       
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Notes:

- This is not dynamic.  It produces 6 columns (but you can use the same idea for a dynamic query).
- The ordering of the results is indeterminate.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want the columns in a particular order, then replace `(select null)` with the appropriate column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it dynamic, you can use the following **`sql`** query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = 'select ' + stuff((
    select distinct ',max(case [PortCode] when ' + char(39) + [PortCode] + char(39) + 
    ' then [PortCode] end) as [PortCode]'
    + ',max(case [CarCode] when ' + char(39) + [CarCode] + char(39) + 
    ' then [CarCode] end) as [CarCode]'
    from [your_table_name]
    for xml path('')
), 1, 1, '');

select @sql += ' from [your_table_name];';
exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Required only static columns, can you give me the same query for static columns?

Comment: @SantoshJadi : Sorry, I didn't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I'm looking for static query.